# In spark Streaming how to reload a lookup non stream rdd after n batches

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Suppose i have a streaming context which does lot of steps and then at the end the micro batch look's up or joins to a preloaded RDD. I have to refresh that preloaded RDD every 12 hours . how can i do this. Anything i do which does not relate to streaming context is not replayed to my understanding, how i get this called form one of the streaming RDD. I need to make only one call non matter how many partition the streaming dstream has

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.....

Comment: I've got an idea but I need to test it out first.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible by re-creating the external RDD at the time it needs to be reloaded. It requires defining a mutable variable to hold the `RDD` reference that's active at a given moment in time. Within the `dstream.foreachRDD` we can then check for the moment when the RDD reference needs to be refreshed.

This is an example on how that would look like:

```scala
val stream:DStream[Int] = ??? //let's say that we have some DStream of Ints

// Some external data as an RDD of (x,x)
def externalData():RDD[(Int,Int)] = sparkContext.textFile(dataFile)
   .flatMap{line => try { Some((line.toInt, line.toInt)) } catch {case ex:Throwable => None}}
   .cache()

// this mutable var will hold the reference to the external data RDD
var cache:RDD[(Int,Int)] = externalData() 
// force materialization - useful for experimenting, not needed in reality
cache.count()
// a var to count iterations -- use to trigger the reload in this example 
var tick = 1
// reload frequency
val ReloadFrequency = 5  

stream.foreachRDD{ rdd => 
    if (tick == 0) { // will reload the RDD every 5 iterations
     // unpersist the previous RDD, otherwise it will linger in memory, taking up resources.
     cache.unpersist(false)
     // generate a new RDD  
     cache = externalData() 
    }
    // join the DStream RDD with our reference data, do something with it...
    val matches = rdd.keyBy(identity).join(cache).count() 
    updateData(dataFile, (matches + 1).toInt) // so I'm adding data to the static file in order to see when the new records become alive
    tick = (tick + 1) % ReloadFrequency
}
streaming.start
```

Previous to come with this solution, I studied the possibility to play with the `persist` flag in the RDD, but it didn't work as expected. Looks like `unpersist()` does not force re-materialization of the RDD when it's used again.

Comment: I will try this and see how it goes

Comment: I am thinking the foreachRdd will probably make 1 call for each RDD so if the condition matches at any batch the call to external will happen as many times as the number of RDD's in the dstream

Comment: @subhankar There's only 1 RDD for each batch interval in the DStream.

Comment: This is just a minor quirk, but why did you do tick%5 and tick+=1 %1000 ? Why not just tick = (tick=1)%5, then (tick==0) in the conditional ?

Comment: @MultiMat that would be indeed equivalent, assuming you meant `tick = (tick+1)%5`. Your suggestion probably shows the intention better as well. Thanks!

Comment: @MultiMat I've included your comment in the code. Thanks again.

Comment: @maasg tick being a local variable, won't it trigger caching again n again from each executor whenever threshold is triggered?

Comment: @AbhashUpadhyaya `tick` is only evaluated in the context of the driver.