# Create an empty DStream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How i can create a new DStram like `sc().emptyRDD()`.

I need to create an empty `JavaPairDStream<String, String>` to union with another JavaPairDStream. I will fill this dstream at the end of batch to use in union at new batch.

full requirement is:
I want to update a List between stages.

1. I have an RDD (of keys) that updated by `updateStateBykey()`. some new
   keys add to it in every batch.
2. I join (Cartesian product) this RDD with some input events.
3. I calculate the results and create a new RDD of keys.

but need to this updatedRDD in next micro-batch. using updateStateByKey is not work for this requirement. so i want to join this updated list with newKeys at the beginning of batch.

Comment: I don't think you need an empty `DStream`. I think that what you need is a mutable reference to an empty RDD that gets updated at each iteration. Look at the example I gave in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944976/in-spark-streaming-how-to-reload-a-lookup-non-stream-rdd-after-n-batches/37001685#37001685

Answer (score 2):

One way of creating an empty `DStream` is by using [`JavaStreamingContext.queueStream`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext):

```
val inputStream = ssc.queueStream(new mutable.Queue[RDD[String]])
```

But, if you need to keep state between batches of the `DStream`, as noted by @z-star, one could use a Stateful DStream in the form of [`PairDStreamFunctions.mapWithState`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.PairDStreamFunctions) for Spark 1.6.x and above, and [`PairDStreamFunctions.updateStateByKey`](http://PairDStreamFunctions) for lower version.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to `DStream` not `InputDStream`. `InputDStream` will update in every batch.

Comment: @majidhajibaba `DStream` is a abstract, you can't create an instance of it. `InputDStream` inherits `DStream`.